# Check if a DATE and TIME has passed 3 days

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string with a date and time in the format `2013-07-01 19:10:05 (Y-m-d H:i:s)`.
When I output data from a database where the **date and time** is stored, I want to see if three days have gone since that **date and time**.

Example:
Stored in database is `2013-07-01 00:00:00`.
3 days after that stored **date and time** would be `2013-07-03 00:00:00`.

If that would be true, I want to echo some text.

I tried with the following but I think I am totally out sailing.

```
if( strtotime('-3 days') < strtotime($row["orderdatetime"]) ) {
   echo " <img src='imgs/warning.png' ></td >";
}
```

Thankful for any kind of help!

Sincerely,
 Andreas

**EDIT:**

This is how my PHP script looks like.

```
if ($row["confirmeddatetime"] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ) {
        $db_datetime = new DateTime($row['orderdatetime']);
        $db_plus_three = $db_datetime->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
        $now_datetime = new DateTime();
        if ($db_plus_three < $now_datetime) {
            echo " <img src='imgs/warning.png' ></td >";
        } else {
            echo "</td >";
        }
```

Can anyone of you identify if something is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using DateTime and DateInterval classes.

```
$db_datetime = new DateTime($row['orderdatetime']);
$db_plus_three = $db_datetime->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
$now_datetime = new DateTime();

if ($db_plus_three < $now_datetime) {
   // this is more than 3 days old
}
```

An alternate approach would be to set a flag in the DB query itself like this:

```
SELECT
    [YOUR CURRENT FIELDS HERE],
    (CASE WHEN NOW() > DATE_ADD(orderdatetime, INTERVAL 3 DAYS) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS three_days_old
    [REST OF QUERY HERE]
```

You could then easily identify by looking at `three_days_old` value whether the item was more than 3 days old.

Comment: Seems that this did it! :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Today one of the records in the database should have triggered that the suggestion should work. I've edited my POST so that you can see how it has been done.

Comment: You have it in a conditional.  Have you done debugging to see if the condition is met? Have you done var_dumps on the applicable variables to verify you are getting the values you expect?

Comment: Didn't realise that the edit was based on your answer, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the easiest way is to get the unix time directly from the database (assuming mysql):

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orderdatetime) AS ordertimestamp...
```

then in your comparison you just need

```
if( strtotime('-3 days') < $row["ordertimestamp"] ) {
   echo " <img src='imgs/warning.png' ></td >";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strtotime converts a time string to a timestamp which is just an integer number of seconds. Just compare to time minus 3 * 86400 (seconds in a day)

Comment: Correct me if I have misunderstood @bitfiddler, but if I get it right, what you suggest is that I compare if **NOW()** is *less than** my stored **date and time** + 3 * 86400?

Comment: If you want to compare in PHP rather than SQL as others have suggested, use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function to get the date as a timestamp value and then compare to time()-(3*84000), time() returns the current time as a Unix timestamp

Comment: How would the code look like? Maybe it is too late for me doing this stuff right now to get it.

Comment: Take a look at Jerry Seeger's answer. It will do the same thing and is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (orderdatetime <= NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS threedays ...
```

you'll get a 1/0 true/false value if 3 days have gone by or not. I suggest not doing such a comparison in PHP, as you'll be forcing a mysql date -> string -> int -> date conversion chain, wasting a lot of CPU cycles when you could just do the comparison directly in mysql.

Comment: Thank you @MarcB. The thing is that I also display the **date and time** while performing this comparison. But I am not a guru at optimizing my storage of data and what best to do to increase performance and consumption of CPU.

Comment: I like this approach, but I think as written it will always return true, unless the order was placed more than three days in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your second example works for me, just be careful with the `add()` function, it updates the value itself. This is a similar example how i use it myself:

```
/**
 * Checks if the elapsed time between $startDate and now, is bigger
 * than a given period. This is useful to check an expiry-date.
 * @param DateTime $startDate The moment the time measurement begins.
 * @param DateInterval $validFor The period, the action/token may be used.
 * @return bool Returns true if the action/token expired, otherwise false.
 */
function isExpired(DateTime $startDate, DateInterval $validFor)
{
  $now = new DateTime();

  $expiryDate = clone $startDate;
  $expiryDate->add($validFor);

  return $now > $expiryDate;
}

// how to use it
$startDate = new DateTime('2013-06-16 12:36:34');
$validFor = new DateInterval('P3D'); // valid for 3 days
$isExpired = isExpired($startDate, $validFor);
```